# Open application after clicking on notification Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to run my application after notification click!

I want to run: app-->com.zaglebiefm.Radio

This file diectory: library-->com.zaglebiefm.library.Notyfication

Notification.class:

```
private void buildNotification() {

        Intent intentPlayPause = new Intent(NOTIFICATION_INTENT_PLAY_PAUSE);
        Intent intentOpenPlayer = new Intent(NOTIFICATION_INTENT_OPEN_PLAYER);
        Intent intentCancel = new Intent(NOTIFICATION_INTENT_CANCEL);

        PendingIntent playPausePending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 23, intentPlayPause, 0);
        PendingIntent openPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 31, intentOpenPlayer, 0);
        PendingIntent cancelPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12, intentCancel, 0);


        RemoteViews mNotificationTemplate = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
        Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);

        if (artImage == null)
            artImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.default_art);

        mNotificationTemplate.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_line_one, singerName);
        mNotificationTemplate.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_line_two, songName);
        mNotificationTemplate.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_play, isPlaying() ? R.drawable.btn_playback_pause : R.drawable.btn_playback_play);
        mNotificationTemplate.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.notification_image, artImage);

        mNotificationTemplate.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_play, playPausePending);




        Notification notification = notificationBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(smallImage)
                .setContentIntent(openPending)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContent(mNotificationTemplate)
                .setUsesChronometer(true)
                .build();


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

            RemoteViews mExpandedView = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_expanded);

            mExpandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_line_one, singerName);
            mExpandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_line_two, songName);
            mExpandedView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_expanded_play, isPlaying() ? R.drawable.btn_playback_pause : R.drawable.btn_playback_play);
            mExpandedView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.notification_image, artImage);

            mExpandedView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_expanded_play, playPausePending);

            notification.bigContentView = mExpandedView;
        }

        if (mNotificationManager != null)
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }
```

I tried some things but they won't work for me.

Any ideas or solutions.

Comment: use this:   Intent intentOpenPlayer = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Radio.class);

Comment: I tried but file i want to run is in different diectory.

Comment: that is not problem. try above method

Comment: app --> com.zaglebiefm.Radio

Comment: library-->com.zaglebiefm.library.Notyfication

Comment: library is included in app?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code instead to launch desired/targetted application activity.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context,YourTargetActivity.class), 0);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

This should work.

Comment: app --> com.zaglebiefm.Radio library-->com.zaglebiefm.library.Notyfication

Comment: Instead of using .setOnClickPendingIntent try using PendingIntent. Also when you post a comment, explain the issue so it is easier for the community to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(this, Splash_Activity.class);
        myintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 int randomPIN = (int)(Math.random()*9000)+1000;
    PendingIntent conIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, randomPIN,
            myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(conIntent);
```

This will work

Comment: i am trying to open application from RadioPlayerServiece.